# Load SVG String to UIImage (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, svg

I have a SVG Data downloaded from Internet in SVG format.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 450" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="450" fill="#E9F0FC"></rect><g transform="translate(0,410)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 8px;"><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(49.5,0)"><text fill="currentColor" ...
```

And I have a `UIImageView` where I would like to show picture from this data.

I was looking for some tutorials, but most of them are outdated or for objective-c.

I tried this

```swift
SVGImageView.image = UIImage(data: svgData)
```

But it says that I can't convert `String` to `Data`

Comment: Can you save the data as a file in the app bundle? If you can, then you can just use `UIImage(named: "my-svg-file")`.

Comment: What is `SVGImageView`? Maybe `UIImage(data: Data(svgData.utf8))`, since in fact according to your error `svgData` is a `String` and not `Data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) for example.

1. Install it using CocoaPods.

   ```
   pod 'SVGKit'
   ```
2. Use it like this:

   ```
    let svgImage = SVGKImage(data: yourSVGData)

    testImage.image = svgImage.UIImage
   ```

The framework also allows to init an SVGKImage from other different sources, for example it can download image for you when you provide it with URL.

Answer (score 1):

Until Xcode 13.x you couldn't load SVG images natively. So the solution is using a third party like SVGKit. Using Xcode 14.x you can use Image("name") on SwiftUI. But, IMO, no good support yet. Frame view modifier doesn't apply over a SVG Graph...

https://github.com/allangarcia/SVG-Image